# How to build an Parent Child in EF 7

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
public class ServiceType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The Service type data has another collection of "SubTypes", which are basically a collection of `ServiceType.Code`. I would like to build a navigation property that references the ServiceType collection.

So I am guessing that I need to build another table to store the Id of the Parent and of the child like:

```
public class ServiceTypeHeirarchy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }  // ServiceType.Id of Parent
    public int ChildId { get; set; }   // ServiceType.Id of Child
}
```

Not sure if I am on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to have many 'sub'`ServiceType` under one 'parent'`ServiceType`.

And if that is indeed the case then you can do something like following:

```
public class ServiceType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ParentServiceTypeId { get; set; }
    public ServiceType ParentServiceType { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ServiceType> ChildServiceTypes { get; set; }

}
```

And then you might want to do an Entity Configuration with `HasMany`, `WithOptional`.

Comment: How would I go about populating that since I wouldn't know the ParentServiceTypeId until I had inserted the ServiceType?  I would still need the Code and Name as they are lookup values.

Comment: The very first or first few `ServiceType` entries can play the role of 'root' entries and going forward you can refer these 'root' service types as 'parent' for creating your 'sub' `ServiceTypes`. Hope this helps :)